# How to format the output to the center in C?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
printf("+--------------+----------\n"
        " Postal number| Tele\n"
        "----------+-----------------+---------------\n"
    "%u             |      %u", number, tele);
```

but right now the output looks like:

```
+--------------+----------
Postal number  | Tele
----------+---------------
03             | 02
```

how to make the `03` and `02` stand at the center of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to center text. You'll have to combine several elements:

1. Figure out how many digits you have.
2. Calculate how many spaces you want before and after the number.
3. Print: `printf("%*s%d%*s", spaces_before, "", num, spaces_after, "");`

`%*s` consumes two parameters - the first is the length, the second is the string to print. Here, I tell it to print an empty string of a given width, which just prints the desired number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a field width in your format string, e.g.

```
printf("+--------------+----------\n"
        " Postal number| Tele\n"
        "----------+-----------------+---------------\n"
        "%8u             |      %3u", number, tele);
```

Comment: @user2131316 try it and see.  it's not hard.

Comment: that depends on the "length" (string output representations) of the number though..

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Corner "+"
#define Wall   "|"

typedef enum { left, center, right } position;

int pos_calc(int width, int max_width, position pos){
    int d;
    if((d=max_width - width)< 0)
        return -1;

    switch(pos){
    case   left: return 0;
    case  right: return d;
    case center: return d/2;
    }
}

char *format(char *buff, int width, position pos, const char *data){
    int len = strlen(data);
    int offset = pos_calc(len, width, pos);
    memset(buff, ' ', width);
    buff[width]='\0';
    strncpy(buff + offset, data, len);
    return buff;
}

int main(void){
    unsigned number = 3, tele = 2;
    const int c1w = 15, c2w = 10;
    const char *c1title = "Postal number";
    const char *c2title = "Tele";
    char c1[c1w+1], c2[c2w+1];
    char c1d[c1w+1], c2d[c2w+1];
    char c1line[c1w+1], c2line[c2w+1];

    sprintf(c1d, "%02u", number);
    sprintf(c2d, "%02u", tele);

    memset(c1line, '-', c1w);c1line[c1w] = '\0';
    memset(c2line, '-', c2w);c2line[c2w] = '\0';
    printf("%s%s%s%s%s\n", Corner, c1line, Corner, c2line, Corner);
    format(c1, c1w, center, c1title);
    format(c2, c2w, center, c2title);
    printf("%s%s%s%s%s\n", Wall  , c1, Wall, c2, Wall);
    printf("%s%s%s%s%s\n", Corner, c1line, Corner, c2line, Corner);
    format(c1, c1w, center, c1d);
    format(c2, c2w, center, c2d);
    printf("%s%s%s%s%s\n", Wall  , c1, Wall, c2, Wall);
    printf("%s%s%s%s%s\n", Corner, c1line, Corner, c2line, Corner);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int number=5;
 int tele=10;
 printf("+--------------+----------\n"
    " Postal number| Tele\n"
    "----------+-----------------+---------------\n"
   "\t%u     |      \t%u\n", number, tele);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my simple library, libtprint: https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint The code is pretty simple, you should be able to understand how it works.

Basically what you need is to play with the fields widths for each column and calculate alignment offsets.

Hope it helps !